# How to add more than one dataframe in python email body

Tags: javascript, python

I want to insert two data frames in my email body and I am able to get one but not both.

Here is my code

```
import smtplib
import teradata
import pandas as pd

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

table =[{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Jan': 150, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': 140}, {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': 215},{'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': 95 }]

table1 =[{'account': 'fgsdgd LLC', 'Jan': 150, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': 140}, {'account': 'fsdgsd Co',  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': 215},{'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': 95 }]
sql_canc_hour = pd.DataFrame(table)
sql1 = pd.DataFrame(table1)


 me = "xxx@gmail.com"
 you = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Account Details"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = " "
html = """\
<html>
<head></head>
<br>Hi Team,\n</br>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```
   {sql_canc_hour}


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("table").addClass("table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive table-condensed");
    </script>

</html>"""
html1 = """ <html>
<head></head>
<br>Hi Team,\n</br>
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


{sql1}


<script type="text/javascript">
$("table").addClass("table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive table-condensed");
 </script> """


 html= html.format(sql_canc_hour = sql_canc_hour.to_html())
 html1= html1.format(sql1 = sql1.to_html())
 # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
 part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
 part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
 part3 = MIMEText(html1, 'html')

 # Attach parts into message container.
 # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
 # the HTML message, is best and preferred.
 msg.attach(part1)
 msg.attach(part2)
 msg.attach(part3)


 # Send the message via local SMTP server.
 s = smtplib.SMTP('XXXX@gmail.com')
 # sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's   address
 # and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
 s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
 print ("Successfully sent email")
```

Output is 
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdENW.jpg)

My objective is to add as many data frames as possible into email body and send email

Answer (score 0):

Just having a quick look at this, I think your issue is less caused by your code and more a result of using two sets of *html* and *head* tags.

Some browsers / clients might not interpret this well and only accept the first occurrence. HTML documents are only supposed to have one set. This is true of *body* tags too.

Adjust your strings to reflect this and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Hi Benjamin,
Thanks for taking time to go through the code, Is it possible to add two data frames in one body rather than creating two parts and consolidating to one at the end.
Let me know if you have syntax for the same